# Does my new bathroom plumbing need a cleanout?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, drain, venting

I am working on new plumbing for an addition we just built. Does anyone see any issues? Do I need a clean-out at the end of the run?

I plan on using a 3" elbow in lieu of a combo to keep everything within the joists below.  Haven't found anywhere stating that is an issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think any time you can add a clean out it is worth the extra 20$ in plumbing and will save many times that if there is a plug that you can get to with a hand snake or larger auger.

Comment: since your P-trap is glued a clean out is must have

Comment: approved ................

Answer (score 0):

Looks reasonable, other than the (hopefully just a sketch issue) shower trap looking S rather than P on the sketch.

Presumably the drawing fails to show whatever constraints keep the shower connection from being more direct (*i.e.* from the sketch, seems like the Wye could just roll over to point more at the trap and simplify your connection, but I assume there are obstacles. If there are not obstacles, do that - it does not need to enter the 3" line facing up - 45 degrees up towards the shower would be dandy, 2 degrees up towards the shower would also be acceptable - it IS a wye. They do that. Taking the dry vent wye off the top is correct.)

Comment: I added an additional picture for context.  Downslope is to the left.  I can spin the p trap and modify the blocking but if it's okay to have it spun upstream and wrap into the wye that would be desirable.  It's going to be a tight turn either way into that wye unless i spin the p trap 180 degrees and enter the 3" further downslope.